# Server inbound redirection can't find a next Restlet

Tags: java, spring, redirect, restlet

I'm trying to add a simple redirect into a web application built in Restlets, and it's proving non-trivial. The task is a simple one: I want to actually redirect all missing files from a web application to the same static file.

I'm using `org.restlet.routing.Redirector` with the following values (I'm using Spring injection):

```
<bean name="router" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
    <constructor-arg ref="trackerComponentChildContext" />
    <property name="attachments">
        <map>
            <entry key="/api" value-ref="apiRouter" />
            <entry key="/statics" value-ref="staticsDirectory" />
            <entry key="/" value-ref="staticsRedirector" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="staticsRedirector" class="ca.uhnresearch.pughlab.tracker.restlets.CustomRedirector">
    <constructor-arg ref="trackerComponentChildContext" />
    <constructor-arg value="{o}/statics/index.html" />
    <constructor-arg value="7" />
</bean>
```

I can play with the file hierarchy relatively simply, but I just want to send anything that doesn't match either `/api` or `/statics` to `/statics/index.html` within the same application.

Restlet is *almost* getting it, and it does seem now to pick up the reference to the correct file, it just doesn't quite serve it.

I've put a working copy of the whole thing (including Thierry's suggestions below) at: https://github.com/morungos/restlet-spring-static-files. What I'd like to happen is something like the equivalent sequential attempts below:

`curl http://localhost:8080/statics/**/*` to hit the corresponding `/statics/**/*`

`curl http://localhost:8080` to hit the main `/statics/index.html`

`curl http://localhost:8080/**/*` to hit the main `/statics/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

I made some tests regarding your issue and I can't figure out how to have your message :-(. Perhaps it's because I haven't the whole code.

In fact, I saw a problem at the level of the `SpringRouter` itself. I would like to attach the redirector with an `attachDefault` and not an `attach("/", ...)` / `attach("", ...)`. The method `setDefaultAttachment` actually does an `attach("", ...)`.

So I made work something with the following updates:

- Create a custom `SpringRouter`

  ```
  public class CustomSpringRouter extends SpringRouter {
      public void setDefaultAttachment(Object route) {
          if (route instanceof Redirector) {
              this.attachDefault((Restlet) route);
          } else {
              super.setDefaultAttachment(route);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a custom `Redirector`. I got the context from the component instead of a child context.

  ```
  public class CustomRedirector extends Redirector {
      public CustomRedirector(Component component, String targetPattern, int mode) {
          super(component.getContext(), targetPattern, mode);
      }
  }
  ```

I then use the following Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="myComponent" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
        <property name="defaultTarget" ref="router" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="router" class="test.CustomSpringRouter">
        <property name="attachments">
            <map>
                <entry key="/api" value-ref="apiRouter" />
                <entry key="/statics" value-ref="staticsDirectory" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultAttachment" ref="staticsRedirector" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="staticsRedirector" class="test.CustomRedirector">
        <constructor-arg ref="myComponent" />
        <constructor-arg value="{o}/statics/index.html" />
        <constructor-arg value="7" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="apiRouter" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
        (...)
    </bean>

    (...)
</beans>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: That seems to help, but it doesn't seem to get right yet. I had to make a couple of edits, so I've updated a model of the complete code, and edited the question with the current status. At least you now have a complete model of the relevant code.

Comment: No, I still can't get the Redirector and static files to interoperate. As soon as I use the Redirector it seems to have the correct file path, but still serves out a 404. I'm wondering whether the static file access is using a pre-redirected version of the Reference, or something like that.